# Basic PHP Script

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a script to do the following:

```
http://mydomain.com/script.php?name=bob
```

That link would output to a blank page with text

```
Hi bob
```

Anyone know what the contents of script.php should be?

Comment: If we tell you, what do you get out of the exercise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php echo 'Hi ', htmlspecialchars($_GET['name'], ENT_QUOTES), ' and welcome'; ?>
```

or simply

```
<?php echo 'Hi '. $_GET['name'] .' and welcome'; ?>
```

You should learn PHP from a book or tutorials. This is not the way to learn it.

Comment: +1 For not the way to go. There are so many tutorials out there that go far beyond this question, in a friendly and easy way.

Comment: Don't forget accepting this the answer. I'm suspicious of that.

Comment: I can't accept for 15 minutes or something after I ask. 6 more minutes to go

Comment: Everyone who upvoted this should have flagged the question instead

Comment: sorry another question. what if I want it to be "Hi bob and welcome" in the page. Basically, text after the 'get'

Comment: @jcolebrand - why? is stackoverflow only for the hard/complicated questions? I'm a complete beginner at php.

Comment: Because @Virendar you have showed no effort in asking this question. A google search would have given you an answer in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

echo 'Hi '. $_GET['name'];

?>
```

Making sure of course to sanitize your variables before you use them for anything.

Comment: This was not a homework assignment. I'm a nursing student, not computer tech. It was for my website. If you want I can link you to where I've implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

if the text that is `name = bob` coming from db. then you can $_GET the name and concatenate that here.

for button or submit

```
onclick="location.href='script.php?name=<?php echo $name ?>'"
```

for text link

```
<a href="script.php?id=<?php echo $name;?>">view</a>
```

write this in script.php

```
<? php echo 'HI'.$_GET['name']; ?>
```

Comment: learning by our self will lead not to forget that much ease.